# Look Up IPs From Text File, Generate Another Text File With Specific Formatting

Tags: nslookup

I'd like a way of looking up all the domains in a text file (one domain per line) and generating another text file with the output as the IP address, a space, the domain name, a space and then the domain name with www. prepending it.

For example, if the source text file contains two lines:

```
1.gravatar.com
abcya.com
```

the new text file would contain 3 lines as 1.gravatar.com has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address:

```
72.21.91.121 1.gravatar.com www.1.gravatar.com
2a04:fa87:fffe::c000:4902 1.gravatar.com www.1.gravatar.com
104.198.14.52 abcya.com www.abcya.com
```

I'm running a Ubuntu derivative and can use nslookup to get the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. However, the source text file is a list of over 2,000 domains - so doing it by hand would take a very long time with plenty of room for error.

And if the answer could allow for no IP address too. If the domain no longer exists (as in the case of alwaysbeready.mybigcommerce.com), nslookup returns
** server can't find alwaysbeready.mybigcommerce.com: NXDOMAIN
So, maybe have NXDOMAIN in place of the IP Address in the resulting text file?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Why do you need the domain name with `www.` prefix? For example `nslookup www.1.gravatar.com` fails.

Comment: Freddy - That is the format of the lines needed in /etc/hosts when used in combination with /etc/nsswitch.conf to whitelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python solution

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket 


#this module is core networking module in Python, 
#can be used to resolve domain names.

sourcefile = 'sourcefile.txt' #file with domain names
outfile = 'results.txt' #file to write the IP addresses

with open(sourcefile, 'r') as inputf: 
    #This opens the sourcefile in read mode to see what are the domains


    with open(outfile, 'a') as outputf: 
        #This opens the outfile in append mode to write the results


        domains = inputf.readlines() 
        #This reads all the domains in sourcefile line by line


        for domain in domains: 
            #This for loop will go one by one on domains.


            domain = domain.strip("\n") 
                #as the every domain in the file are in newline,
                #the socket function will have trouble, so strip off the newline char


            try:
                resolution = (socket.getaddrinfo(domain, port=80,type=2))
                for ip in resolution:
                    outputf.write(str(ip[4][0])+" "+domain+ " www."+domain+"\n" )
            except:
                outputf.write("Could not resolve "+domain+" www."+domain+"\n")
                #getaddinfo("domain") gets all the IP addresses.
```

Input :

```
1.gravatar.com
abcya.com
allaboutbirds.org
google.com
akamai.de
```

Output :

```
192.0.73.2 1.gravatar.com www.1.gravatar.com
2a04:fa87:fffe::c000:4902 1.gravatar.com www.1.gravatar.com
104.198.14.52 abcya.com www.abcya.com
128.84.12.109 allaboutbirds.org www.allaboutbirds.org
216.58.197.78 google.com www.google.com
2404:6800:4007:810::200e google.com www.google.com
104.127.218.235 akamai.de www.akamai.de
2600:140b:a000:28e::35eb akamai.de www.akamai.de
2600:140b:a000:280::35eb akamai.de www.akamai.de
```

Comment: Vignesh SP - Wow! The formatting is perfect. Just how I need it. And the script ran in just a very few minutes - so it's fast too. I do have a few questions:

Comment: 1. Many IP addresses match what nslookup finds, but many do not. For example, the results.txt file show 147.75.96.23 for abcya.com, but nslookup shows 104.198.14.52 for abcya.com. And the results.txt file shows 104.25.231.13 for allaboutbirds.org, but nslookup shows 128.84.12.109 for allaboutbirds.org. Then again aliceinwonderland.ca matches, both results.txt and nslookup show 198.168.252.18. Do you know why some are different?

Comment: 2. The results.txt file is only showing one IP address per domain name. For example, the results.txt file shows just one IP address for allcancode.com, 216.239.32.21. But nslookup shows eight, 216.239.32.21, 216.239.34.21, 216.239.36.21, 216.239.38.21, 2001:4860:4802:32::15, 2001:4860:4802:34::15, 2001:4860:4802:36::15 and 2001:4860:4802:38::15.

Comment: 3. And that brings up IPv6 - they're aren't any. The results.txt file only shows IPv4 addresses.

Comment: The script is resolving `www.allaboutbirds.org` which has multiple IP addresses. The `gethostbyname()` function gets only one IP address in a resolution, so it just prints either `104.25.231.13 or 230.13`.

I think you are just resolving `allaboutbirds.org` with nslookup which gives the IP that youd posted in the comment.

If you want to get all the IP addresses including IPv6, you can use the function  `getaddrinfo()` in place of `gethostbyname()`. But please check out how that function works.

This can be done in shell scripting too, but too much of hacks required with `awk` and `sed`.

Comment: @EricBradshaw Check my updated answer, it has what you need.

Comment: Vignesh SP - That's exremely close to what I am needing. Your updated answer fetches all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. I'll need to break them up into separate lines but, doing that one at a time is nothing in comparison to searching over 2,000 domains one at a time. I'm accepting that as the best answer. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I still accept the script above as the best answer - it does very, very close to what I was asking. But, can it be tweaked or maybe some other script be run on the results.txt to make each line an IP address, a space, the domain name, a space and then the domain name with www. prepending it?

Comment: Can you post an example result that you want?

Comment: 2a02:26f0:8f:29f::35eb akamai.de www.akamai.de    
2a02:26f0:8f:2be::35eb akamai.de www.akamai.de    
23.214.155.115 akamai.de www.akamai.de

Comment: Updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly, precisely what I need! Thank you! Thank you! You've saved me days and days of work!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

A hacky `bash` solution parsing the output of `nslookup`:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_lines() {
        ips=($(nslookup -type=A "$1" | grep -Po -m1 "Address: \K.*"))
        ips+=($(nslookup -type=AAAA "$1" | grep -Po -m1 "has AAAA address \K.*"))

        if [ ${#ips[@]} -ne 0 ]; then
                printf "%s $1 www.$1\n" "${ips[@]}"
        else
                printf 'NXDOMAIN %s www.%s\n' "$1" "$1"
        fi
}

while read domain; do
        if [ -z "$domain" ] || [ "${domain:0:1}" = "#" ]; then
                # skip empty line and line starting with '#'
                continue
        fi
        get_lines "$domain"
done < "$1"
```

**Explanation:**

1. For IPv4 we `grep` for the IP address after `Address:`

   Example:

   ```
   $ nslookup -type=A 1.gravatar.com
   Server:         8.8.8.8
   Address:        8.8.8.8#53

   Non-authoritative answer:
   Name:   1.gravatar.com
   Address: 192.0.73.2
   ```
2. For IPv6 addresses we `grep` for the IP address after `has AAAA address`

   Example:

   ```
   $ nslookup -type=AAAA 1.gravatar.com
   Server:         8.8.8.8
   Address:        8.8.8.8#53

   Non-authoritative answer:
   1.gravatar.com  has AAAA address 2a04:fa87:fffe::c000:4902

   Authoritative answers can be found from:
   ```
3. If both IPv4 and IPv6 fail, the output is `NXDOMAIN domain www.domain`.
4. Empty lines or lines starting with `#` in the input file are skipped.

**Output:**

My test domain file looks like this:

```
$ cat domains.txt
1.gravatar.com
abcya.com
alwaysbeready.mybigcommerce.com
# this is a comment followed by a newline

allaboutbirds.org
aliceinwonderland.ca
allcancode.com
```

Test run:

```
$ ./getips.sh domains.txt
192.0.73.2 1.gravatar.com www.1.gravatar.com
2a04:fa87:fffe::c000:4902 1.gravatar.com www.1.gravatar.com
104.198.14.52 abcya.com www.abcya.com
NXDOMAIN alwaysbeready.mybigcommerce.com www.alwaysbeready.mybigcommerce.com
128.84.12.109 allaboutbirds.org www.allaboutbirds.org
198.168.252.18 aliceinwonderland.ca www.aliceinwonderland.ca
216.239.32.21 allcancode.com www.allcancode.com
2001:4860:4802:32::15 allcancode.com www.allcancode.com
```

You can redirect the output to a file with `./getips.sh domains.txt > results.txt`.

Comment: Freddy - Thanks for the bash script. I really like that it uses nslookup as that seems to grab all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for a given domain (when I use the command nslookup 1.gravatar.com for example). However, there are still a couple of things:

Comment: 1. There is only one, or no more than two IP address per domain (where there in some cases should be eight, like for allcancode.com) and only IPv4 addresses are shown.

Comment: 2. The results.txt shows two lines for every result (the second line always being the domain prepended with www.) regardless of whether the script finds one or two IPv4 addressses.
So, each result in your results.txt looks similar to this:

Comment: 23.217.138.107 23.202.231.166 aliceinwonderland.ca
 www.aliceinwonderland.ca
And I was hoping for this:
23.217.138.107 aliceinwonderland.ca www.aliceinwonderland.ca
23.202.231.166 aliceinwonderland.ca www.aliceinwonderland.ca

Comment: (1) Changed to output max. one IPv4 IP and one IPv6 IP, hope that's okay. (2) Every IP is now on its own line.